# Git deploy to Azure app service from Gitlab fails

Tags: azure, ssh, gitlab, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am attempting to [deploy to an Azure app service from Gitlab](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/) but ran into a problem. The deployment fails immediatley with:

> Host key verification failed.\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists.\n\r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch origin --progress

I've deleted the deployment configuration in the App service a few times and recreted to make sure the SSL URL for the Gitlab repository is correct. I've also tried addkng my key into the Gitlab deployment keys but it wont let me as its already there, so I knw the key is definitely correct.

Searching around on the web suggests to remove the host from the known hosts file, but as this is on azure there is no known_hosts in the /ssh folder (`Kudu`->`Console`->`D:\home\.ssh`) so I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @LDJ. Did you ever solve this problem? I tried creating the `known_hosts` file, adding Gitlab to it or removing it but nothing worked. I finally stopped trying and resolved to use the Bitbucket integration by auto-pushing from Gitlab to Bitbucket. If it helps, this options is available under Settings/Repository in your Gitlab repo.